# Understanding Python Twisted Looping Call - Save the return of the LoopingCall function

Tags: python, twisted, event-driven, twisted.web, twisted.internet

I am using Twisted and making a Looping Call every x seconds.

The function I use for the looping calls makes a return statement.

```
def f():
    # Obtain stuff
    return stuff

def main():
    LoopingCall(f).start(x)
```

How can I retrieve the return result of f?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to "retrieve" the result of `f` from?  `LoopingCall` is just called by the reactor, so this question doesn't really make sense.  If you want `main` to somehow access the result that doesn't make sense, because `main` is run once, but `f` is run a potentially unlimited number of times.

So perhaps you just want to do this, instead:

```
def f():
    # Obtain stuff
    return stuff
def do_something_with_f():
    result = f()
    do_something(result)

def main():
    LoopingCall(do_something_with_f).start(x)
```